# Ember: Idiom for ArrayController to loop through same-named ObjectController

Tags: ember.js

I have the following pattern recurring throughout my app, and I was wondering if there is a way to clean this up:

Array Controller:

```
App.ThingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()
```

Template for Array Controller (using Emblem)

```
each thing in controller
  = render 'thing' thing
```

Object Controller:

```
App.ThingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()
```

I don't like having that intermediary template that has only those two lines.

I looked into itemController as a potential solution but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `render`ing inside your `each` loop you could just include the code, and then use `itemController`.  This would consolidate your templates into one, but still allow you to use the `ObjectController`.

```
{{each thing in controller itemController="thing"}}
  {{thing.name}}.id = {{thing.id}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: In your example does the handlebars template example represent the "things" template?

Comment: Yes, it would be the `things` template.

Comment: I see. That works in one sense, because then I would have one template instead of two, but I feel like the code would be in the wrong place. I'd be putting the code that belongs in the `thing` template in `things`, so this isn't the solution I was hoping for.